# Rotate HDR picture from background with Blender Render/Internal, not Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine

I tried to rotate it with cycles and nodes, it works, but I am not yet an experienced in making materials with nodes in cycles, so I would prefer to stay in blender render, and if possible rotate the HDR background image as it is done with nodes in cycles, but with the Blender Render. I cant find a way to do it.
thanks in advance guys.
sorry my bad english.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rotate the HDR background image in Blender Render (Internal render engine) by using the Mapping Size property in the Texture panel.  Use the X axis if you have a normal setup and increment or decrement from the default 1.00 setting.  You range of change is limited to +/- .9 before you will receive distortion.